# Is this a parenthetical phrase or an apposition?

Tags: punctuation, terminology, commas, writing-style, question-mark

Consider the following

> What are you laughing at, my silly hat?

and

> What are you laughing at? My silly hat?

Which of these is correctly punctuated, and if the first example is correct, what is the name of the grammatical structure? Would the noun phrase after the comma be considered a parenthetical phrase? Is it an example of apposition?

Comment: How about it possibly being a vocative? For instance: *"What are you laughing at, my silly hat?" said the cat-in-the-hat to his hat.* -- (Both of your original examples are fine.)

Comment: Discounting the unlikely reading that 'my silly hat' is a vocative (cf 'What are you laughing at, my good man?', there needs to be a stronger stop than a comma. A colon would do, but a dash would be more common: 'What are you laughing at – my silly hat?' Two sentences is fine too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second example is correct: the first is ambiguous. It seems as though the speaker is asking his or her *hat* what it's laughing at. The two elements before and after the comma in the first example are self-contained questions (despite the second question being dependent on the first), and therefore should be split apart as in the second example.

Answer (score 0):

The second example is correct. txteclipse provided a worthy explanation. Beyond it, it's worth noting that, as the second question is dependent on the first, it can also be punctuated thusly:

What are you laughing at? my silly hat?

...though this seems to be less common in modern usage.